# Chain redirect https > http

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm having a issue and i'm trying to understand if this is possible.
My website is redirecting all the requests from http to https from AppServiceProvider.

The problem is that the 404 page is redirecting to homepage and i get two 301 redirects as follows:

http://url.com/some_unexisting_page (301 to) > http**s**://url.com/some_unexisting_page (301 to) > http**s**://url.com (200)

So instead of displaying the 404 page at https://url.com/some_unexisting_page i'm doing another 301 redirect to homepage.

My questions is if its possible to skip the 2nd redirect and go from http://url.com/some_unexisting_page (301 to) -> http**s**://url.com

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Laravel.  But the redirect in question is definitely possible using Apache redirect or using Netflix Zuul.